# Adding a Place in Google Maps through KML

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, kml

Is it possible for me to do this: people will input the name of a place in my site's textbox and then upon submission, that place will be placed in the database, have my site's embedded google map updated (display all the original places and the added one) and can be toggled?

Currently, I already had a working code of getting the latitude and longitude of a certain place. Placing that information in the database is also done. I can also generate a KML file from my latlng-database. What I wanted is to have the generated kml used by my website's map to get the necessary points and be toggled whether to be displayed or not and will reflect any added area/place. To be more specific, adding a place is only by KML file, meaning the textbox in the site will be added depending on which KML the user will want to change.

Or is it better to use OpenLayers?

Thanks!